# Filter the JSON data using angular 4 filters

Tags: angular

I am fetching the content(data) from local JSON file using http in the following way,

```
 getIssuerTestCases(totalPage) { 
        // console.log(formdata);
        const searchurl = `assets/data/issuer_test_cases.json`;

        return this.http.get(searchurl, {}).map(
           result => {
               console.log(result.json());
               return result.json();
           },
        );
        // .filter(result => (result.content.initiated_by).sessionStorage.getItem('initiatedby') > -1);
      }
```

And i want to filter the JSON content based on the user role. if the user role is `issuer`, i want to fetch only the '**issuer**' data. can any one help to filter the array.

```
 {

    "content": [
        {
            "testcase": "PREQ_001 - Payment request",
            "iterationcount": "COMFORT",
            "test_case_id": "PREQ_001",
            "initiated_by": ["issuer"]
        },
        {
            "testcase": "PREV_002 - Payment reversal",
            "iterationcount": "COMFORT",
            "test_case_id": "PREV_002",
            "initiated_by": ["issuer", "acquirer"]
        },
       {
            "testcase": "PREV_0 - Payment reversal",
            "iterationcount": "COMFORT",
            "test_case_id": "PREV_0",
            "initiated_by": ["CDF"]
        },

   ]
}
```

Comment: where ur data is storing Like if i know some where ur data is storing then its easy 4r u 4r storing data

Comment: @Gosoddin, i am able to fetch the data, but i want to filter it and show it in a table.

Comment: in result ur getting data?

Comment: yes, but i am getting all the content and need to apply filters before render in a table

Comment: man try my ans 1st it will give u exeact information

Answer (score 2):

You can try with this solution.

```
console.log(result.json());
let jsonData= result.json();
return jsonData.content.filter(data => data.initiated_by.indexOf("issuer") > -1)
```

Comment: Its working with small change, data.initiated_by.indexOf("issuer") > -1

Comment: Ok I have update answer . it's working aceept answer

Answer (score 0):

Plese Try this

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.result= this.books.filter(
      book => book.store_id === this.store.id);
  }
```

In place of books but ur data

Answer (score 0):

Use can check for index of **issuer** in **initiated_by** array and filter it if present.

Sample code:

```
return result.json().content.filter(item => ids.indexOf("issuer") !== -1);
```